# K2 SP 2010 workflow deployment package

Tags: sharepoint-2010, k2

When I am creating the workflow with SharePoint Workflow Integration activity the deployment package tool give me an error

```
"one or more of the wizards that are used in the process are not currently supported by this tool"
```

What to do ? any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

K2 package and deployment doesn't support the following artifacts:

> **Unsupported Artifacts**
>
> The following artifacts are not supported at this time:
>
> - Artifacts utilizing Workflow Integration (such as InfoPath and SharePoint).
> - Artifacts designed using the K2 Designer for SharePoint.
> - Non-K2 artifacts (such as SharePoint lists and libraries).
> - Custom environment configurations (for example, changes to configuration files like 'K2HostServer.exe.config', cannot be packaged. These configurations must be manually applied to the target environment).
>
> **Supported Artifacts**
>
> Artifacts designed using K2 Studio, K2 for Visual Studio and the K2 Designer can be packaged and deployed. These
>   include:
>
> - SmartObjects.
> - SmartObject Data.
> - Workflows.
> - Forms.
> - Views.
> - Supporting artifacts such as Categories, Roles, Service instances, Notification events and Environment library fields.